# MasterPage has a control in it, and the controls OnClick comes back as method not found in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a linkbutton in my masterpage:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="Transfer" Text="Transfer"></asp:LinkButton>
```

in my code behind

```
        protected void Transfer(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              // Codez
        }
```

Says that no such method Transfer exists.

Any idea why or how to fix it?

MasterPage has no <%@ Blah %> on the very first line unlike my other pages, could this be the cause? I tried putting one in and specifying the codebehind but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your master page should have an <%@ Master .... %> tag at the top of the page.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>
```